# How to find the real value of a float variable in .NET

Tags: .net, sql-server, floating-point

I have a DB table where one of the columns is of REAL type. I need to compare the values of this column in a .NET environment but the casting to REAL messes up the number.

For example, saving **15.02** in the DB will actually save the value **15.020000457763672**.
Later reading from the DB and trying to compare 15.02 to the value gotten from the DB will yield unexpected results.

Since I'm stuck with the REAL data type because of backwards compatibility, is there any way get the "real" value of the variable in .NET code without having to construct a float number bit by bit?

using the example above, how can I transform 15.02 => 15.020000457763672 in .NET code?

Comment: This is how floating point works. If you want to compare floating point numbers, you need to look for an acceptable range, not an exact match.

Answer (score 0):

create the type as float and then convert it to double.
    float f = 15.02f;
    double d = Convert.ToDouble(f);
    f.ToString("r") = > "15.020000457763672"